# Azure - settings for browser caching of js, css files for Web App

Tags: azure, caching

Azure Windows Web App with instances in Amsterdam, US and Hong Kong.

Need to optimize for browser cached files - so that once a user has visited a page in the app and downloaded whatever js, css, fonts or images - the browser caches these locally.

Then - only when a cached file is updated - it then breaks browser cache and does an https call to get the newer file version.

Thus minimizing latency, bandwidth and # of http requests from the user browser standpoint.

Typically have 90-96 PageSpeed scores - so the pages are optimized - but seems it's way slower than could be perhaps because these unchanging js, css, font and image files may be re-downloaded unnecessarily?

Once a page is visited once during a session it's wicked fast for the rest of the session.

But - on login the next day there is latency again for first render of each page - then it's wicked fast again.

Kinda seems like a TTL expiry setting or something like an old school IIS ETag HTTP response header type of thing?

ASP.NET C# 4.7 Windows Web App

Any geniuses know how to optimize for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a caching issue, it's more likely to be your application unloading due to being idle for too long.

To overcome this you need to ensure your App Service Plan is S1 (Standard) or higher and enable the "Always On" option for your site.  To do this:

Azure Portal -> Your Web App -> Application Settings -> Always On -> Enabled

You can scale up your App Service Plan without any downtime if it's currently at the free or shared tier:

Azure Portal -> App Service Plan -> Scale Up